# Jekyll Minimal Theme Shows 404 On "category/***" Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I have a problem with “[/category/***](https://66shayan.github.io/category/life/)” pages in my [Blog](https://66shayan.github.io/category/).

The /category/ and /tag/ root pages are working fine. But /category/*** sub-pages show 404 error and basically the blog generates no category page.
How do I fix this issue?

[My repository link.](https://github.com/66shayan/66shayan.github.io)

PS: I really checked everything I could think of.

Comment: Categories is a string not a list as pointed in the docs: [_Therefore, depending on whether front matter has `category: classic hollywood`, or `categories: classic hollywood`, the example post above would have the URL as either `movies/horror/classic%20hollywood/2019/05/21/bride-of-chucky.html` or `movies/horror/classic/hollywood/2019/05/21/bride-of-chucky.html` respectively._](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#categories)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε But how to fix my issue? I read the docs but no possible solution for my situation!

Comment: Use a string: `Categories: Life`, that would at least make your post reachable in this category. Then, Jekyll does not create a page for a category, if you want this, you'll have to create it yourself/

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for the reply, but i have "categories: name" already in posts. Look at this post: https://66shayan.github.io/out-of-comfort-zone-bs/ 
And you will se at the bottom it has the category "life": https://66shayan.github.io/category/life/ But it has 404 error.
Or take a look at this URL: https://66shayan.github.io/category/
The "life" category is already exist. But when you click on it had 404 error.

My site was generating these URL just fine. I dont know why it stopped working all of a sudden. The site suppose to generate category URLs.